# Unknown SAXException: Requested schema is not found in local repository

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, persistence.xml

I try to connect my Maven app with my DB with GlassFisch server. I also tried MySql and Postgres, but I got the following error by deploy:

```
Exception Occurred :Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [mavenproject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : org.xml.sax.SAXException: Requested schema is not found in local repository, please ensure that there are no typos in the XML namespace declaration.. Please see server.log for more details.|#]
```

It occurs always after I added my first entity from database.

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakartaee}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20211205</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
<version>2.7.7</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>8.0.25</version>
 </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="com.tutorial_mavenproject4_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<class>model.Invoice</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="postgres"/>
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

The 2.1 version in the persistence.xml is generated, I also tried with 2.7.7 but I got the same error.

This is the stack trace of the exception:

```
  Exception while deploying the app [mavenproject4-1.0-SNAPSHOT] :   org.xml.sax.SAXException: Requested schema is not found in local repository, please ensure that there are no typos in the XML namespace declaration.
    org.xml.sax.SAXException: Requested schema is not found in local repository, please ensure that there are no typos in the XML namespace declaration.
    at    com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.resolveEntity(SaxP  arserHandler.java:229)
at    java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:111)
at   java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1133)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:662)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2694)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2069)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:829)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3063)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:294)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ExtensionsArchivist.open(ExtensionsArchivist.java:155)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.PersistenceArchivist.readPersistenceDeploymentDescriptor(PersistenceArchivist.java:120)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.WarPersistenceArchivist.open(WarPersistenceArchivist.java:69)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:381)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:372)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:247)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:256)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:217)
at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:137)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:182)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:206)
at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:72)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:857)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:797)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:354)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:361)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:221)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:202)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:241)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:108)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:287)
at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:156)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 3):

I read on this website, [monkeyways](https://www.monkeyways.asia/wp/programming/java/java-jakartaee-xml/892/), that what you need to do is edit your:

- web.xml
- persistance.xml

They suggested that you change the version and URL to this:

- [web.xml with edited line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZzMy.png)
- [persistance.xml with edited line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okcnH.png)

That is, the web.xml should have:

```
<web-app version="5.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd">
```

And the persistance.xml should have:

```
<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
```

It is my first time posting here so I hope this is clear enough.
You can also read [here](https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/) to understand more about these Jakarta XML Schemas